# Black screen in simulator

Tags: swift

I created a file that had a button bringing you to another ViewController, and it worked fine. But all of a sudden when I would run the simulator, the screen on the iPhone would turn white and then black and I am not able to click the button or even see it. Below is the error that popped up in the debug error. "mmmmm" is the name of the file

2018-06-29 18:18:44.326922-0400 mmmmm[3774:225271] [Application] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Comment: check "is initial View controllrt" is checked in Storyboard?

Comment: nope its not, that arrow must have gotten deleted. How do I add it back? @Osman

Comment: i post a answer with image

Answer (score 3):

Click on your `Main View Controller`. In the `Attribute Inspector` on the right, select `Is Initial View Controller` and the arrow will reappear. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you have the **checkmark** for `Is Initial View Controller` enabled in the `Attribute Inspector` as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Maybe a little more explanation will help the OP.